# Second form doesn't load properly

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create an alarm clock and I want a second form to show when the alarm starts.

The problem is that it partialy loads and I get the loading cursor when I hover over it. At first I though I should just wait but nothing changes.

[image]

this is how it should be:

[image]

this is the function that calls the second form:

```
private void ring() 
{
    if (System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm") == temp && songisplaying == false) 
    {
        soundplayer.PlayLooping();

        songisplaying = true;

        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            this.Show();
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }

        wakeupForm win = new wakeupForm();
        win.Show();
    }
```

This is the code of the second form

```
public partial class wakeupForm : Form
{
    public wakeupForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

This is the code that calls the ring function:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    num1.Maximum = 2;
    num3.Maximum = 5;
    num4.Maximum = 9;
    var timer2 = new System.Threading.Timer(e => ring(),null,TimeSpan.Zero,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    ofd.Filter = "WAV | *.wav";
}
```

Comment: Edit your question specifying the name of the form that you are talking about. Is it `wakeupForm`?

Comment: Also add the code of the constructor for that form, I assume the `wakeupForm`.

Comment: Could you post the code of your wakeupForm ?

Comment: The second form is nothing special in therms of code it just has a button and a label

Comment: OK, edit your question again and provide the line of code who calls the `ring` method and the timer1 tick method implementation and what is the interval of that timer. Are you calling `ring` from different thread?

Comment: Could it be that in the solution explorer the name of the form is Form2 but in the explorer I changed the class name to wakeupform? It doesn't show any errors so I guessed it's ok

Comment: First question to ask, is the sound coming out? If yes, have you tried to debug your own code? It looks like a threading problem. You're trying to open up a window from nonui thread which is just not capable of doing it.

Comment: It is pretty remarkable that you see the window content at all.  Oh, wait, it is the design view.  The thread used by the timer is not suitable to display a window whatsoever, it does not have a dispatcher loop (Application.Run) and does not have the correct thread state.  Displaying a window on the secondary thread is rocket-science in general, very high odds that you get a random deadlock.  Just don't use that timer class, favor the one in the toolbox.  It fires its Tick event on the UI thread, your window will look just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Threading.Timer` runs `ring()` on a thread from the thread pool. `ring()` in turn tries to instantiate a form which should always be done on the main thread (all access to windows forms should be done from the main thread).

Use the following instead:

```
private void ring() 
{
    if (System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm") == temp && songisplaying == false) 
    {
        songisplaying = true;
        if (this.InvokeRequired) 
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(()=>{ringOnMainThread()}));
        else
            ringOnMainThread();
    }
}

private void ringOnMainThread()
{
    soundplayer.PlayLooping();
    timer1.Start();

    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        this.Show();
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }

    wakeupForm win = new wakeupForm();
    win.Show();
}
```

Note that I have moved `songisplaying = true;` to avoid a race condition.

Comment: This kind of code gets too many programmers into trouble.  Why test InvokeRequired when you *know* that it always must be true?  If it is false then something Really Bad happened, never just plow on anyway.  Throw an exception to alert the programmer about the bug, he forgot to disable the timer when his window closed.  And why use Invoke when BeginInvoke gets the job done?  Invoke is notorious for causing deadlock, BeginInvoke can't deadlock.

Comment: @jakev If you're not sure what to do I will give you perfect advise. Start of by stopping to just copy and paste the code from the internet, use your common sense/knowledge while rewriting some solutions from the web.

Comment: It is true that as it stands, `InvokeRequired` is not really needed. `System.Threading.Timer` will always call `ring()` in a thread from the thread pool, never from the main thread. But what if later the OP changes to winforms `Timer` or he just wants to call `ring()` from some other code (not from the timer) on the main thread? eg. say he has a "Test alert" button that simply calls `ring()` to let the user listen to the sound he selected. (Granted, always calling `Invoke` is not going to hurt in this case, but this may not always be the case)

Comment: There was a right parenthesis missing on line 7. I have edited my answer accordingly

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis "_(Granted, always calling Invoke is not going to hurt in this case, but this may not always be the case)_" It will hurt on performance when you would call Invoke on the same thread it will be executed at the end. That's why If this method can be called from ui and nonui threads it's better to check if invoke is required.

Comment: @Mateusz I completely agree, that is why I said "in this case". In this specific case, the performance hit does not matter and being called at the end does not matter. But in general what you say is true, and that is the very reason I used `InvokeRequired` in my answer.

Comment: OK. Update, I tried using the code above and the second form now works just fine. @Mateusz I will and thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should stop your timer when the form is shown.

(Check your timer interval. If it ticks more than one time in one minute, it will hit your ring() method more than one time).

You should stop your timer in the ring() method and restart on FormClosing of your wakeupForm.

```
    private void ring() {

    if (System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm") == temp && songisplaying == false) {
        soundplayer.PlayLooping();



        timer1.Stop();//Stop your timer.



        songisplaying = true;

        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            this.Show();
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }

        wakeupForm win = new wakeupForm();
        win.Form_Closed += win_Closed;
        win.Show();

    }

     private void wnd_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        timer1.Start();
     }
```

Comment: Even though the  'ring()' function is called the code is never executed a second time because the flag songisplaying is set to true. As a result the second form is called only once!

Comment: And why you start a, already started timer ?  Could you post the timer tick method ?

Comment: Stopping the timer seems not to cause trouble as the code execution is based on the flag that is set later on in the code ( `songisplaying` ). This may be caused by some thread race for that particualr flag but to resolve it `songisplaying` flag should be marked as `volatile`.